# How do I get hero shards for Suicide Squad Harley?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

I bought<sup>(I'm a mug I know)</sup> the Suicide Squad Harley Quinn pack when it was up the other day. I've checked [various](https://community.wbgames.com/t5/Player-Guides/Character-shard-Gear-locations-v1-3-wip/m-p/1503150#M6) [guides](https://community.wbgames.com/t5/Player-Guides/Character-shard-Gear-EXTRA-dROP-RATES-v1-3-wip/m-p/1503155#M7) and none of them seem to know how to get the shards for this Harley. For obvious reasons I'd like to get shards so I can upgrade her star rating.

Is there a way?

Comment: That is actually one question about Injustice 2 I do not know. I can only assume Arena tokens, challenges, or randomly in the shop however I haven't seen any myself.

Comment: @Ramirez Me neither and the few posts I've found, some linked above, mention having found nothing on this hero too. (Side note: Go me for asking one you don't know the answer to!)

Comment: Based on that guide you linked I can only assume Suicide Squad Harley will be an Arena reward since it mentioned never seeing Predator Batman in the Hero chests and I saw Predator Batman in the Arena Store as a reward. I imagine they are going to be difficult to get unsurprisingly.

Comment: @Ramirez Annoying of course then... will teach me to spend my money on it :P

Comment: Honestly I find my purchase of Harley Quinn to be a huge boon in the game. You get an amazingly powerful hero with a full set of gear, and on 10 hero box purchase. I've been using Harley and all the heroes I obtained from my boxes to tear through the arena up to elite level.

Comment: @Ramirez Oh don't get me wrong she's my best hero by far...